# Can I efficiently do multidimensional slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Let's say I have a Python list `L` of arbitrary dimensions and of known shape `shape: List[int]`.

I'd like to slice this list multidimensionally having one interval and one step for each dimension. Note that my task is developing an efficient algorithm without using builtin Python slices (`L[start:end:step]` notation, or any other Python-exclusive trick), just being able to access list elements one at time.

```py
L = [[[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]],
     [[7, 8, 9],
      [10, 11, 12]]]

slices = [(0, 2, 2),
          (0, 0, 1),
          (0, 1, 1)]

result = some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L, slices)
print(result)

# [[[1, 3]],
#  [[7, 9]]]
```

Note that in my example `L` has three dimensions, but I'd like my algorithm to be as general as possible, hence offering support for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: Try to make your title describe the specific question. "Can I efficiently do multidimensional slicing in Python?" is my own recommendation, but choose your own as long as it lets someone tell if what they want to know is _actually the same question_, not just if it's about the same general topic.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't be surprised if doing this _efficiently_ would mean building your own C extension. Anything implemented in Python is going to have a lot of overhead involved just in using the built in magic / introspection support -- unless you got stuck somewhere specific, and thus can narrow your question to something more focused than "please fill in the magic here".

Comment: You have `(0, 0, 1)`, which is an empty slice, so why is your expected result not empty?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, the ultimate goal in fact is to implement it in C, only I have difficulty developing an algorithm, and python seemed simpler than C in regards to the procedural clarity that such a question requires.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode my fault I didn't wrote it in the question. Both start and end of the slices are included, not like Python does that excludes the end. Hence `(0, 0, 1)` would be the equivalent of python slice `(0, 1, 1)`

Comment: Personally, btw, my strong preference for a high-performance numeric-computing language is [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/). Quite possible to get performance on-par with C while having code that reads as well as Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBLasMwEN3rFLO06BQip5800Bv4BoMQqiM7A7ZkZGXR07tS7BZDF@3bzeP9mOkzXYM/nqa4LBfXwRxGZ0bbc2vs0IfI6ToaNq31yXTsL1WDMA/culmeBWRwBz6kjVupgujSLXpo7oRF@EBo4X2T0aPSYqeiv1uJ9XcxnbNd/jQVdCECA3uI1veuKn0PKjdKLUSTa4konzXCMadsTnpCeEZ40RrFShG9IpwQ3nYidUBQ2atqrbVYB5TA6nDPqyXuhhSy6H@RJSBviW6@Dam84f9fFlNkn6rVKsWyfAE)):

```
def some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L, slices):
    if not slices:
        return L
    a, b, c = slices[-1]
    return [some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L[i], slices[:-1])
            for i in range(a, b+1, c)]
```

If you hadn't unpythonically made the end indexes inclusive, it would be simpler ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDdaoQwEIXv8xRzqcsUGu3PdqFv4BsMQxA3ugOaSMxe9OndBG0RelF67vJxzkeY@SvevKvPc1jXq@1h8ZM1UztIZ9px8EHibTJiutZF04u7Fg3CMkpnl/KiIEV6cD7ubEM5wcZ7cNCow4P@lpPwt58uT5rLH2FO7wMIiIPQusEWp72Ye6xUA59ARBqhQqiTZ9/SC8Irwhszqg0RvSOcET4OJf2MoNNWV8ysNnMWFonXSVni4SsZ5u4vWGXIKtjlPsY0/8c51RzExWKblmpdHw)):

```
def some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L, slices):
    if not slices:
        return L
    return [some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L[i], slices[:-1])
            for i in range(*slices[-1])]
```

**Edit:** Since I was kinda challenged to a duel, here's my similarly optimized version, seems about 10% faster than blhsing's:

```
def donttalkjustcode2(L, slices):
    *rest, (start, stop, step) = slices
    slice = L[start : stop+1 : step]
    if rest:
        return [donttalkjustcode2(sublist, rest)
                for sublist in slice]
    return slice
```

**Edit 2:** Interesting... I replaced my list comp to be closer to blhsing's, and against my expectation, it became even *faster*:

```
def donttalkjustcode3(L, slices):
    *rest, (start, stop, step) = slices
    slice = L[start : stop+1 : step]
    if rest:
        sliced = []
        for sublist in slice:
            sliced.append(donttalkjustcode3(sublist, rest))
        return sliced
    return slice
```

Benchmark results:

```
4.566 μs  donttalkjustcode
3.043 μs  donttalkjustcode2
2.525 μs  donttalkjustcode3
3.405 μs  blhsing
```

[Try the benchmark online!](https://tio.run/##vVRdjtowEH7PKeZltc7iUgLd7TYSN@AGVoRCYhZ3HceyHVW9W8/QK1GPnRAg2apP9QOYme@bn28G65/u1KrNqzbn89G0DTjRcOFANLo1DgzXvHRJUvMj1K1yrpTv3zvrqrbmZEfBSlFxm@YJ@COOoFrX26IJj@GuMwp2wVBSOFCoYNvD2KesSK5QbJqFiWJIxHIPTy@R8RxbAwKEAlOqN04w/iLzGdJivur1pOwnw62jQKwrjf@2rtX4yXV6qTLgwtWbdiwgIQ/QRRYuXBeDBhhu0j2b1mG7gxSYGQm3TQ2N9RBsL2S/kSpY5pvc/OcmA6v2NFYkf6s/v@kyspal1lzVZNrDrUDpvaSRPqNIkOQgT1aot4kQbed058ZSfZvVO/4k0UNhZETEj5OQPOLuO6Ygg6ofqxvkRepSt5qkt3zv8/yodI4kWECWjzrPav1v2uKpfOF3Q5mXPgCnGxjr7jERROGjoXBpZ8fL8mLYsOtRRbGTZIf1Meb/sWsKm4L2EdgXCs8UXorBwthXCq8Uvo2QbEUh88RsXRRFEkcWBrkKwdYpvSoHjYifGDGAH/SxUxWy77eQTh@QqWlDh3VLEhzNfnyPnvu182p10tlxGojDpAgNyUfxcDsboUh8fIksm0Nd5kOIYSBIutrulILqmgM322zlj1@8zxBul7DaCOXI48Nyc4Tfvyw8wgMQB0@Q8RfPxnjL/V6VDd/v41xLa7l/A0opSUwO2@1QBlsVoYfegQ1Hhw9FcENIU2oiuaIXRzpek7Gg9Hz@Aw)

Comment: Ranges and unpacking operators were exactly what I meant with "python-exclusive tricks" :(

Comment: Meh, that's trivial to translate. I hope you don't expect me to write a `while` loop :-)

Comment: @Giuppox I guess you want [this](https://tio.run/##lZHdisMgEIXvfYq5jKyUmO5Pu2zfIG8gIiE1jZCoqKXs02c1NhLYi2Xn7hxmvjmj9juMRh9P1i3LVQ7gzSzF3N1UL7rpZpwK4yyU6DsdxKD0tWoJ@En10uNPBLHUANqEp5etVE6Gu9PQoiz8fQpwAcZXvTZHmYcO1tgKZ9hmsjp3PkY1yWh/bT7l@x0Je@islTHY38mZ4iU8LhQFLxu82cXzhZsURruj8l6E2nQRY5RAQ@AY2U8meyXwRuCdc4KyxdgHgROB866J1gRonKUN5xzlnQlY1SuvwaREBEhm6v9lJgDmqLzwP/4PWad0qPIoRsvyAw), but it's too disgusting for me to include it in the answer :-P

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works. Is there also a way to accomplish this without function recursion?

Comment: @Giuppox Sure. Always. But recursive is probably much simpler here, and is available in other languages.

Comment: Nice recursive approach. +1. I've added an iterative solution if you're interested.

Comment: @blhsing I'll have a closer look later, for now I'll +1 because it supports my "recursive is simpler" argument :-D (and I verified that it gets the example right)

Comment: Thanks. Yes recursive approaches are almost always simpler and easier to understand, but comes with a performance cost associated with the overhead of making function calls, as shown in the benchmark results in my updated answer.

Comment: @blhsing Well... looks like you have optimized your solution, including even an extended list slicing which the question explicitly requests not to do (which is why I didn't).

Comment: Ah, well I did not notice this somewhat peculiar requirement of the question. I've updated my answer accordingly then. With no slice notation the iterative approach is about as fast as the recursive approach, since I guess managing the stack myself incurs about as much overhead as making a function call after all.

Comment: Hmm I did not notice your updated answer with solutions using the slice notation until I made the comment above. Will check them out.

Comment: After some fiddling around, I ended up with only very marginal improvement by switching back to a queue-based implementation. It proves that saving states into tuples, adding the tuples to a stack/queue, popping them and unpacking them to restore states is too much Python bytecode to go through for the approach to overcome the efficiency of the built-in C-implemented stack management of Python function calls. Good lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

For an iterative approach you can use a stack of tuples to keep track of the output list, the input multi-dimensional list, and the input list of slices at each level:

```
def some_magic_algorithm_i_cant_find(L, slices):
    output = []
    stack = [(output, L, slices)]
    while stack:
        sliced, lst, (*rest, (start, stop, step)) = stack.pop()
        if rest:
            for i in range(start, stop + 1, step):
                child = []
                sliced.append(child)
                stack.append((child, lst[i], rest))
        else:
            sliced.extend(lst[i] for i in range(start, stop + 1, step))
```

[Try the code online](https://tio.run/##lZLdboQgEIXveYq5lJZsVrc/2yZ9g30DQoxRVLIIBDBtn97yY6qbvWnnQgKe73DG0Xz7UavT2dhl6XgPTk@8nppBtHUjB22FH6da1G2jfN0L1RUXAk6Kljv8jiCUnr2ZPXwAZWnvfNNe47bIbwhsRFZ8jkLyrMsWCYuKjoB0gSgeLE9rENmwOq9NfHKDcbBO6MFoU@BfXvQQmc0wVq8tCBAKbKMGvneDRyhXx1skVhsCdltH@8oxD40xPHyLJMT3opRv1WRRaowKRlJKvDFcOn6bYL2Cf/mIZ@xvnWRXy/1s1ToXhC6xEUqDpiJwCgHWy@gTgWcCL4wRlI8ofSVwJvC2E5VHAmVgy4oxhvIY03CPya/CZJc9Hkb93WE0CMMPrc8y/ir/@MmQsUL5IqMYLcsP)

Benchmark shows that this iterative approach is somewhat slower than @don'ttalkjustcode's recursive conversion of the same code, however, for reasons most likely attributed to the fact that stack management implemented in C through function calls is much faster than managing the stack on our own in Python:

```
4.501 μs  donttalkjustcode
5.004 μs  blhsing

4.417 μs  donttalkjustcode
5.628 μs  blhsing

4.787 μs  donttalkjustcode
5.124 μs  blhsing
```

[Try the benchmark online](https://tio.run/##rVRRjtsgFPz3Kd7PamGL0jhpt9uVcoO9gWVFxMYJXQwIsNq9W8/QK6U8sOMo1kqrqnzYBmaG92aQ7Vs4Gb19su587pzpIcheyACyt8aFcVakHRmEC8YoP20enRns4Y1BYwYdGEivZCMy2HHdIicjPe@tEkXRig5ao0Pg6vXH4ENjWkFeGCSip88FxJEmLQPloyZ5cCK9feAuvn0wFp/CUgo7qGoGF35iyw6QkaVwdMaBBKmxpKO41oFPUI5aM3yuYMWtFboli4JjYZWMB@M5lCamUF7MGiNf/ArIz/CP1ZHVnAiD06NMdu2gTl7q48IsMwQ7hORENi/w5hWnJO9c2UMz4udJKpFxtxV/zPNEXVljCb3wF67/o/M4mlhgO3f0fjAJSJegVN@IyaDU2G1my9z@Y3bZ/aJ4wUaqKmI2DLY1G8@qvjD4yuCxnlaq6huDJwbfZ0i5ZlBGYrmp67rIGaZk10lsQ9lV4biI@MUiCsTku0E3yL69zGy6WUWBTe7nJrdjNNGxQQU/B4I4lENokp0NxIuYfxlE8f7Q8ueJPuWBhKtLTBnooT8ItyvXcVD4DOnjomid1IHc3622Hfz57eEe7oAEeIBSPEYyyq32e817sd/nALj38T8FXCmSz4bdbqqiWucsxw3sNW9EKaKkD6Tnliih2WWDzp/FXBA9n/8C)

Comment: Sure. Already reviewing them like I commented. Please note that I have already updated my benchmark comparison based on the no-slice requirement of the OP so that it is apples-to-apples. :-)

Comment: Well... still slightly different apples :-). That one of mine still computes `slices[:-1]` for every call instead of once before the list comp. And list comp appears to be slower for such small lists. And the recursion goes all the way down to elements rather than stopping one level earlier. [This version](https://tio.run/##jY5BCgIxDEX3niLLqRZB3IjgDbzB4KJMU62WtjQZ0NPXtjM4ghuzSAjkvfz44lvw@0NMOWs0oINnVu5xH4mHoLE7SyBnByRxXEGptmgJjlhCt07YJrFKZRKHWDtGIeAE/UXCh2@0NVCJSVXLhAQWrIek/BW/PbCB3exazpcEWxUjet39BC7Belse1z9CNBId4eKYeXxy5afz/3JMtoQ8Jj9rcn4D), where I pretty much copied your code and turned ...

Comment: ... your recursion simulation into real recursion is about 10% faster again. I agree with your other comment, simulating the C-recursion in Python is costly :-)

Comment: Haha agreed on the slightly different apple reasoning and the new code being a true apple-to-apple conversion. Updated the benchmark comparison in my answer accordingly. Thanks for the good fun. :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Okay, this is definitely getting out of hand :-). What I wanted to develop by asking this question was an efficient algorithm to implement in C. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143795/algorithm-for-slicing-multidimensional-array

Comment: @blhsing Yes, good fun :-). Btw I just realized the question did ask for something efficient. Somehow I had overlooked that and was just trying to make it work...

Comment: @Giuppox Hmm, well, maybe you should've made it a C question then :-P

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode C's a lot less clean than Python for explaining an algorithm :(

Comment: @Giuppox Well if you were to implement both approaches in C I strongly suspect that the needle will tilt back in favor of iterations. You can find many such comparisons for other programming languages with a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion+vs+iteration+performance). My earlier comment on don'ttalkjustcode's answer reflect this "common knowledge" that iteration is in general faster than recursion. Just turns out that it is not the case in Python. :-)